# Windows Phone 8 alternative for Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I know you can start a new browser in WPF trough the launcher method, but what is the alternative if you want to make your windows phone app launch a new window with a hyperlink (or youtube page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a [`WebBrowserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, i got my answer there i had been looking at it but forgot to include Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;